# Asp Chart - Dealing with Missing X Axis Values

Tags: asp.net, charts, aspchart

I have a asp.net chart which plots Hourly data on X axis. However, sometimes the data been binded does not contain data on weekends. So after Fri 11 pm, the next data is Mon 00:00 am. But asp chart still plots all the slots between Fri 11 pm till Mon 00:00 am. I would want the chart to skip plotting the missing slots on x axis, as the data itself does not contain those slots.

I am setting 
AxisX IntervalType="Hours" Interval="1", but even taking it out does not change the output.

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some kind person told me about Series.IsXValueIndexed Property.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.series.isxvalueindexed.aspx

This works well, now!